# How does Ponstan treat headaches?

Tags: medications, pain, headache

I was having a headache and it remained this way for 3 to 4 hours. Then I took "Ponstan" . My headache was completely gone immediately.

What active ingredient is in Ponstan and how does it work? Also, is it normal for Ponstan to have such a quick effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The active ingredient in Ponstan is [mefenamic acid](http://www.netdoctor.co.uk/medicines/aches-and-pains/a7366/ponstan-mefenamic-acid/). It is categorized as a non-steroidal anti-inflammatory drug (NSAID).

It works [because it](http://livertox.nih.gov/MefenamicAcid.htm)

> is a cyclo-oxygenase (Cox-1 and -2) inhibitor and blocks the production of intracellular prostaglandins that are important in pain and inflammatory pathways. Mefenamic acid has analgesic as well as anti-pyretic and anti-inflammatory activities, but is used largely for treatment of pain.

Basically, like a lot of painkillers, it inhibits the transmission of pain signaling.

As for speed, how fast NSAIDs lead to less pain depends on a lot of things, including the severity of the pain or when the patient last ate, it can't really be generalized. A very fast relief might also be caused by [the placebo effect just by having taking medication.](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/05/110523075010.htm)